# Set text of a certain td in a html-table - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

How do I set text of a a certain cell (td) in a html table with jquery properly?

I've earlier created this row dynamically

```
 $('#productOrderTable').append('<tr id="prodBasketPaymOptIdRow1" style="display:none"><td></td><td></td><td> i want to set text here </td></tr>');
```

So I have an id for the row and want to set text for the 3rd column in the table.

I know I can use span-tag instead to identify the td but it think its more simple this way since in reality I have more than one td in this row to change. If I use span-tag i need one for each td.

thanks in advance!!!

Comment: There are many ways, you can use `$('#prodBasketPaymOptIdRow1 td').eq(2)`

Comment: "*[In] reality I have more than one td in this row to change*" - how about describing the problem you're facing in full, so that we might help you solve your problem appropriately and specifically? That way our answer might be of more use to you, and of increased relevance to those seeing this question in future. Is it only this cell in this one row? Multiple cells in this one row, or multiple cells (in the same column(s)) in multiple rows? Incidentally, you need to show your `<table>` as well, showing enough of your code so that we can (easily) reproduce your problem: think "*[mcve]*".

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "#prodBasketPaymOptIdRow1 td:nth-child(2)" ).append( "Your text" );
```

[For Referance](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "#prodBasketPaymOptIdRow1 td:nth-child(3)" ).text( "i want to set text here" );
```

https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Answer (score 0):

you can use last-child property :

```
$( "#prodBasketPaymOptIdRow1 td:last-child" ).text( "Your text" );
```